# How bout a "The Wolfram Language" tag?

Tags: discussion

So people can link questions that discuss Mathematica free Wolfram Language topics can identify them as such. Or maybe a MathKernel tag.

Comment: [related discussion](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1152/looking-ahead-to-wolfram-language).

Comment: btw, [tag:wolfram-language] is blacklisted on this site, so you won't be able to create it. [tag:kernel] already exists.

Comment: Didn't know! Thanks. Will save me much embarrassment, perhaps being blacklisted myself!

Comment: Also, discussion here: [comments](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/37936/how-to-get-list-of-duplicates-when-using-deleteduplicates#comment114140_37936).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As I have already argued against such a tag, here are a few points:

- Since *Mathematica* is an IDE for, based on and written in the Wolfram Language, this would practically require the retagging of all questions on the site that is not about the front-end...
- ... but since even the front end (at least a large part of it) is written in *Mathematica* (in Wolfram...), almost all questions should be retagged. Since it would add nothing to the site, no one wants to do such a huge task, I'm sure.
- No matter how you call the language/IDE in 2013+, all existing releases were named *Mathematica*, so no one can change that retrospectively. Ok, theoretically he *can* but I doubt it's in their interest. I assume, that we, on the other hand, don't want to (perhaps even can't?) rename *Mathematica*.SE to WolframLanguage.SE. That is of course another question.
- Even if Wolfram Language will be the default word in the future to refer to anything that we refer to as *Mathematica* at the moment (even if WRI will rebrand *Mathematica* to something else), I don't see the pressing urge to catch up with (marketing) trends that quickly, without even seeing the next release.
- Even if Wolfram Language is the official name, I don't see why we should emphasize it with a definite article ("the").
- One can argue, that users searching from the outside for "Wolfram Language" could find our site more easily if it is soaked with such tags, though even now the first post about WL ([Is Mathematica an Implementation of the Wolfram Language?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/37557/is-mathematica-an-implementation-of-the-wolfram-language)) is the 8th hit when googling "Wolfram Language", and we can assume that our hitcount will increase as the phrase is used in more and more posts. Perhaps we could add some reference points in our FAQ about WL, but that is again another question.

Perhaps Wolfram become the chosen name not because of obvious reasons but because of Wolfram has the highest melting point of all elements, indicating it's here and is going to stay, no matter how hot it will be.

Comment: I agree; a Wolfram Language tag would create problems that don't seem to have good answers.  I'm thinking about a possible future when many/most? of the questions are about using WL will be about using it in the cloud, on rasberryPi, as run by the kernel, when compiled, etc. Since all of that is hypothetical, perhaps a "we'll see" approach is best.

Comment: Regarding your last sentence, from Wikipedia _"Tungsten with minor amounts of impurities is often brittle and hard, making it difficult to work. "_

Comment: @GeorgeWolfe We have tags for those — [tag:raspberry-pi], [tag:kernel], [tag:compile], etc. When _Mathematica_ becomes available in the cloud (publicly), we can create a [tag:cloud] tag...